# Query inside a query SQL

Tags: sql

so I am trying to do a query where I need to select the top 5 product with the highest price, and then select the top 3 from those top 5 with the lowest unit price.

I currently have the top 5 with this query

`select top 5 * from Products order by UnitPrice desc`

but I cant figure out how to do another select in order to select the 3 with the lowest unit price, any tips? I have tried looking for a select inside a select or a subquery but it didn't help, thanks in advance.

Comment: please tag with the database platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want rows 3-5 ordered by `UnitPrice`, you can use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select p.*
from products p
order by UnitPrice desc
offset 2 rows fetch first 3 rows only;
```

This is Standard SQL, which SQL Server also supports (SQL Server being the most common database that uses `top`).

Comment: thanks that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try nested queries.

```
select top 3 *
from (
  select top 5 * from Products order by UnitPrice desc
) a
order by UnitPrice;
```

The result will come out in the reverse order so, if the output order is a requirement, than a second nested statement is needed.

Comment: this will give me a syntax error on the second order by

Comment: Corrected the query. it was missing the table alias.